# PHP 7.1 CLI Connection to remote DB with SSL Fails with Abort Trap: 6

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I have a PHP CLI script and I used this to set up a mysql connection over SSL:

```
    $DBlink = mysqli_init();
    mysqli_options ($DBlink, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
    $DBlink->ssl_set('[ValidPath]/client-key.pem', '[ValidPath]/client-cert.pem', '[ValidPath]/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL)
    $link = mysqli_real_connect ($DBlink, 'IP', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

I expect this would set up a connection to the remote Mysql Server (Google Cloud SQL) over SSL but, the script reports Abort Trap 6: I think this an C error? After some googling I thought perhaps access to the .pem files was the case. They are world readable [ValidPath] is fully qualified.  I know the .pem files are good because they are the same ones used with MySQLWorkBench and the connection is fine over SSL. If I comment out the $DBlink->ssl_set line then I get `Connect error (1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)`
So it seems like my script is talking to the server. It appears the ssl_set is causing the Abort.

I followed the instructions on Google Cloud SQL for network authorization. And as I said. Connecting to the same instance with MySQLWorkBench works perfectly. Also, connecting with:

```
mysql --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem \
             --host=[INSTANCE_IP] --user=root --password
```

Works perfectly as well. So, it appears something is goofed with PHP?

I am using the script with PHP CLI version 7.1.8 on MacOS 10.12.6.

```
SSL info from php -i | grep SSL

SSL => Yes
SSL Version => SecureTransport
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => supported
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

I am stumped. Anyone run into this before? Is the SSL Version not compatible?

Comment: uhh, are you setting the certificate after mylsqi_connect? it might be that you're only only person who's ever tried that, and that there indeed is a bug with it. most people load the certificates BEFORE connecting

Comment: No, it is before, the very next line after the ssl_set is: $link = mysqli_real_connect ($DBlink, 'IP', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

Comment: I was following the advice from (https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_ssl_set.asp)

Comment: PHP Manual says to use ssl_set before mysqli_real_connect() https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

Comment: It's probably due to the strict host verification: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-sql-discuss/4HNvmq7MpU4/kuSjhkS2AwAJ
You can work around this by using Cloud SQL Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the SSL verification failure should be straightforward, but the challenge is that PHP crashes with `Abort Trap: 6` and does not print out meaningful error message to explain the root cause.

There are multiple possible reasons. I ran into the issue when I do:

```
$mysqli->real_connect("<host>:3306", $user, $password, $database, NULL, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

but this works:

```
$mysqli->real_connect("<host>", $user, $password, $database, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

I also saw one StackOverflow question where changing from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" solved the problem, in case the database is listening to localhost. You might run into other reasons for failure as well.

In general these approaches might help you to root cause:

1. Configure PHP to enable error logging in `php.ini`. Perhaps meaningful error message will be printed out.
2. Try to connect to the database from mysql command line tool, to verify SSL connectivity.
3. Search for sample code on the internet, e.g. https://github.com/search?q=MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT&type=Code, compare with your own code to find differences.